# debian stretch 9.3 insert disc labeled

Tags: debian-installer

i keep having this ""Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 9.3.0 *Stretch* - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171209-12:11'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]" when ever i try to install a compiler on my debian 9.3.
hw can i fix it

Answer (score 5):

Your `sources.list` file is probably referencing the CD as well as various online repositories.

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and comment out the reference to the CD/DVD.  Then run `apt-get update` then run the `apt-get install build-essential`.

If you don't have any online repos listed in your `sources.list` file you can generate one online at https://debgen.simplylinux.ch